# Quero chamar um método public List<String> no main

Tags: java

```
public class Conteudo {   
    public List<String> Matriz(String[] array){

        String CaminhoArquivo=("C:\\Users\\jessica borges"
                + "\\Downloads\\CalculadoraMatrizes-20190315T112959Z-001"
                + "\\CalculadoraMatrizes-20190315T112959Z-001"
                + "\\CalculadoraMatrizes\\src\\ArquivosMatriz\\matrix.txt");

        List<String> conteudo = new ArrayList<>(); 
            try {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CaminhoArquivo));

     String linha;
                while ((linha = in.readLine()) != null) { 
                   int var[] = new int[conteudo.size()];
                    conteudo.addAll(Arrays.asList(linha.split(" ")));
                return conteudo;    
            }   
             in.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        } return conteudo;
    }
}
```

Preciso chamar esse método no método main, estou fazendo assim (porém dá erro):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   chamarMatriz();
}
public void chamarMatriz(){
   Conteudo ct = new Conteudo();
   List<conteudo> oct  = new List<conteudo>();
    ct.Matriz(conteudo);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método main é estático ele não tem acesso aos métodos não-estáticos dentro da classe, para isso você precisa instanciar primeiro a classe que contem o método chamarMatriz:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   ClasseQueTemOMetodoChamarMatriz classe = new ClasseQueTemOMetodoChamarMatriz();
   classe.chamarMatriz();
}
```